# How to display image in ionic 3 which is coming in rest response?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to display Image in Ionic 3 which is coming form Rest API. I am using a library called `angular/platform-browser`;

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';    
    let url = 'http://10.75.0.101/port_3480/data_request?id=cam_image&Device_Num=103'
        this.httpNative.get(url, {}, {}).then((res:HTTPResponse) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
          this.images=res.data;
          this.showPage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.images;
          alert(this.showPage );        
          }).catch(err=>{
            console.log("error:"+JSON.stringify(err))              
        })

        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e)
        });
```

HTML code.

```
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(showPage )">
```

Comment: We are not seeing any issues in the code. Might be issue in the HTTP response. Have you tried accessing the URL in your browser, image is getting download ?

Comment: yeah I tried that its working in browser @SureshKumarAriya

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: can you console log example of response and this this.images? console.log(this.images)?

Comment: this is response I am getting from console.log  @SergeyRudenko    ÿØÿà\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000ÿÛ\u0000Å\u0000 \u0016\u0018\u001c\u0018\u0014 \u001c\u001a\u001c$\" &0P40,,0bFJ:Ptfzxrfpn¸®np Ú¢®¾ÄÎÐÎ|âòàÈð¸ÊÎÆ\u0001\"$$0*0^44^ÆpÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆ\u0002\"$$0*0^44^ÆpÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÿÀ\u0000\u0011\b\u0002Ð\u0005\u0000\u0003\u0001\"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0002ÿÄ\u0001¢\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: not yet I have implemented it in  different way for now but that's not the correct way I an still searching for the solution @TusharKotecha